How to configure output template for JSON Formatter in Serilog .NET
I have added configuration for logging in JSON file using Serilog. Default generated file has lot of properties, I want to customize that.
{
    "@t": "2024-09-06T06:34:39.4252863Z",
    "@mt": "HTTP {RequestMethod} {RequestPath} responded {StatusCode} in {Elapsed:0.0000} ms",
    "@r": [
      "204.5695"
    ],
    "@tr": "60a424ff01d97aa4907011f243f917e2",
    "@sp": "636431c6c9201beb",
    "RequestMethod": "GET",
    "RequestPath": "/api/films/10",
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "Elapsed": 204.5695,
    "SourceContext": "Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware",
    "RequestId": "0HN6E7NRLV2U2:00000002",
    "ConnectionId": "0HN6E7NRLV2U2"
  }

I tried using Serilog.Expression using below configuration
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "Serilog.Sinks.File",
      "Serilog.Expressions"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs/log-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 10485760,
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "shared": true,
          "flushToDiskInterval": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs/logjson-.json",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 10485760,
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "template": "{ {@t, @mt, @l: if @l = 'Information' then undefined() else @l, @x, ..@p} }",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact",
          "shared": true,
          "flushToDiskInterval": 1
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext"
    ]
  }
}

In program.cs file
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, config) => config.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration));


I've used template but it is not applying on JSON file logs. I've installed Serilog.Expressions NuGet package as well.

"CompactJsonFormatter" is a formatter. "ExpressionTemplate" is also a formatter. You can only use one of them.
{
  "Name": "File",
  "Args": {
    ...
    "formatter": {
      "type": "Serilog.Templates.ExpressionTemplate, Serilog.Expressions",
      "template": "{ {@t, @mt, @r, @l: if @l = 'Information' then undefined() else @l, @x, ..@p} }\n"
    },
    ...
  }
}


Thanks @Qiang, when browsing through comments of Serilog author blog comment section I got that.
